# Phing alternative for fixlastline from ant

Tags: ant, phing

I'm rewriting build.xml file from Ant to Phing and everything goes fine with one exception.
I need to add new line at the end of each appended file but I can't find any alternative for `fixlastline="true"`.

In Ant it was

```
 <concat destfile="${libraryFilePrefix}.js" fixlastline="yes">
     <!-- many filesets -->
 </concat>
```

In Phing it's like

```
 <append destfile="${libraryFilePrefix}.js">
     <!-- many filesets -->
 </append>
```

Is there any attribute that works like `fixlastline` or maybe I need to find another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, one of the approaches (and possibly the only one) is applying **replaceregexp** filter on each fileset. You only need to apply **filterchain** at the beginning and it will do the job for each `fileset`, like this:

```
<append destfile="${libraryFilePrefix}.js">
    <filterchain>
        <replaceregexp>
            <regexp pattern="([^\n])$" replace="$1${line.separator}" ignoreCase="true"/>
        </replaceregexp>
    </filterchain>

    <!-- many filesets -->
</append>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Phing 3.x the [AppendTask](https://www.phing.info/phing/guide/en/output/hlhtml/#AppendTask) is aware of the fixlastline attribute. Your Ant script provided is now working as expected

```
    <project name="concat-supports-fixlastline" default="concat-fixed-lastline" basedir=".">
        <target name="concat-fixed-lastline">            
            <concat destfile="${libraryFilePrefix}.js" fixlastline="yes">
                <!-- many filesets -->
            </concat>
        </target>
    </project>
```